# Trailing slash is not redirecting properly to html page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I added below code in web.config

```
<system.webserver>        
<httperrors errormode="Custom" existingresponse="Replace">
<remove statuscode="404"/>
<remove statuscode="403"/>
<error statuscode="403" responsemode="Redirect" path="Error/ErrorMessage.html"/>
<error statuscode="404" responsemode="Redirect" path="Error/ErrorMessage.html"/>
</httperrors>

<defaultdocument enabled="false"/>

</system.webserver>
```

Now when I enter url say "http://localhost:10335/test" It is redirecting properly to ErrorMessage.html page

but when I enter trailing slash after test say "test/" It is redirecting to url 
"http://localhost:10335/test/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/Error/ErrorMessage.html" saying "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try put a slash before your Error, ie:

```
<error statuscode="403" responsemode="Redirect" path="/Error/ErrorMessage.html"/>
<error statuscode="404" responsemode="Redirect" path="/Error/ErrorMessage.html"/>
```

Comment: And as i state the path "Error/ErrorMessage.html" is working for "http://localhost:10335/test" ..but trailing slash after test like "test/" then it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the / before the path to error.html file  , as you must be getting HTTP Error 404.20 - Not Found which is creating unwanted URL 
No default document.After reproducing the issue ,Following settings should work:

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <remove statusCode="403"/>

      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="Redirect" path="/Error/Error.html"/>
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="Redirect" path="/Error/Error.html"/>

    </httpErrors>

      <defaultDocument enabled="false"/>
```